# Equivalent code in c#?

Tags: c#, exception, methods, anonymous

I am analyzing a program in the Exceptions section, but i don't understand what this piece of code do:

```
if (obj.ValidationExceptions.Exists(
    delegate(Exceptions.ValidationException x) {
        return x.Type == Exceptions.ValidationExceptionType.Error;
    }))
        return false;
```

Can anyone can put this code in other simple  other way, avoiding using anonymous methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses `Exists` method from `List<T>` type to verify, whether any exception from `ValidationExceptions` is of type `Exceptions.ValidationExceptionType.Error`.

It is more less the same as

```
foreach(var validationError in obj.ValidationExceptions)
{
    if(validationError.Type == Exceptions.ValidationExceptionType.Error)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```